# Creating a Tumblr with a theme that only displays a single page or post

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm trying setup my Tumblr with a theme or template that will give me a super simple layout with only a few pieces of information displayed.  I'm basically looking to recreate something similar to this ad agency site:

[image: screenshot of Publicis & Hal Riney tumblr]

This would be super simple to just do in HTML, but I want to add a blog loop to the home page in a few months so I'd like to set up the Tumblr backend now.

Any ideas how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

With a little tinkering to personalize and simplify to your personal disgression, the [Linear theme by Peter Vidani](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/5136) makes a very simple, clean aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

A tumblr theme is just plain HTML with some variables.  So just stick the HTML page you want as the theme and tumblr will display it for you.